# Php artisan serve in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, artisan-serve

I am new in laravel development. I am using latest version 9 of laravel, when I write `php artisan serve` in git bash or in VS code terminal after sometime it gives an error. I attached a screenshot of an error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
composer install
composer update
php artisan optimize:clear
```

This will clear all the cache of the application

Comment: I have tried this but still showing same error

Comment: the error is inside vendor folder it should work by above command

Answer (score 3):

run php artisan optimize command